# C# generics, cross referencing classes for state pattern

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to get into C# generics and have created a state machine with the state pattern and now I try to refactor.

I have a state, which has a reference to the object it's working on.

```
public abstract class AbstractState<T> where T : StatefulObject {

    protected T statefulObject;

    public AbstractState(T statefulObject) {
        this.statefulObject = statefulObject;
    }

}
```

and I have the object which has states, this should have a reference to its current state.

```
public abstract class StatefulObject<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : AbstractState<StatefulObject<T>> {

    public T state;

}
```

But it does not work ("the type cannot be used as type parameter 't' in the generic type or method").

What I want to achieve is something like this :

```
public class Monster : StatefulObject<MonsterState> {

}

public abstract class MonsterState : AbstractState<Monster> {

}
```

Is this possible? If it's not this way, is there another? Thx.

Comment: How are you declaring `StatefulObject` as a generic type (2nd snippet) and using it as a non-generic type (1st snippet)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *abuse* interfaces and variance to achieve that:

```
public interface IState<out TObject, in TState>
    where TObject : IStatefulObject<TObject, TState>
    where TState : IState<TObject, TState>
{
}

public interface IStatefulObject<in TObject, out TState>
    where TObject : IStatefulObject<TObject, TState>
    where TState : IState<TObject, TState>
{
}

public abstract class AbstractState<TObject> : IState<TObject, AbstractState<TObject>>
    where TObject : IStatefulObject<TObject, AbstractState<TObject>>
{
    protected TObject Object { get; private set; }

    public AbstractState(TObject obj)
    {
        Object = obj;
    }
}

public abstract class StatefulObject<TState> : IStatefulObject<StatefulObject<TState>, TState>
    where TState : IState<StatefulObject<TState>, TState>
{
    protected TState State { get; set; }
}

public class Monster : StatefulObject<MonsterState>
{
    public Monster()
    {
        State = new IdleMonsterState(this);
    }
}

public abstract class MonsterState : AbstractState<Monster>
{
    protected MonsterState(Monster monster)
        : base(monster)
    {
    }
}

public class IdleMonsterState : MonsterState
{
    public IdleMonsterState(Monster monster)
        : base(monster)
    {
    }
}
```

Whether it's actually a good idea is dubious, such code may be too confusing.

---

You could also go with the simpler (but less strongly-typed) approach:

```
public abstract class AbstractState
{
}

public abstract class StatefulObject
{
}

public abstract class AbstractState<TObject> : AbstractState
    where TObject : StatefulObject
{
    protected TObject Object { get; private set; }

    public AbstractState(TObject obj)
    {
        Object = obj;
    }
}

public abstract class StatefulObject<TState> : StatefulObject
    where TState : AbstractState
{
    protected TState State { get; set; }
}

public class Monster : StatefulObject<MonsterState>
{
}

public abstract class MonsterState : AbstractState<Monster>
{
    protected MonsterState(Monster monster)
        : base(monster)
    {
    }
}
```

This won't ensure you won't be able to assign, say a `PlayerState` to a `Monster`, you should check that at runtime.

Comment: One of the drawbacks of this design is that you can assign to a Monster any state is not constrained that the state is a MonsterState

Comment: @MarcCals yes, I actually misunderstood OP's goal. I rewrote the answer.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski It works. I will need some time to see through this :) First the compiler complained about the in and out in the interfaces and I had to set the target to .net4.0 (I am working with Unity). Thanks :)

Comment: Ah hm, but the downside is, it does not work with Unity ... it needs 4.0 for the in and out, but Unity supports only 3.5. Too bad. So I am rolling with my lame approach, but I guess an update will come somewhen ... :)

Comment: Um, I was fiddling around a bit with your first answer and I split my classes into : public abstract class AbstractState , public abstract class StatefulObject , public abstract class AbstractState<T> : AbstractState where T : StatefulObject , public abstract class StatefulObject<T> : StatefulObject where T : AbstractState , public class Monster : StatefulObject<MonsterState> , public abstract class MonsterState : AbstractState<Monster>. And it works. Everything is strongly typed. Am I missing something? If not, could you add your first answer again? It seems to be a better answer.

Comment: I didn't know you were using Unity for this. I added a modified version of the previous approach to the post, but the old answer's explanation was actually misleading, I misunderstood your design.