# Cross reference generic type C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create some state machines for the little game I'm making with Unity.
I started with some enums, but as I want to do some multi layer state machines, it's not really a good way.
Looking around the internet, I found some interesting ideas, and I came to this kind of implementation

```
public interface IStateMachine
{
    public BaseState CurrentState { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseState
{
    private IStateMachine _ctx;
    // ... other state stuffs
}
```

That I'm trying to adapt to use a generic type for the context, like this

```
public abstract class BaseState<T> where T: IStateMachine
{
    private T _ctx;
    // ... other state stuffs
}
```

But that won't compile, saying that I forgot a `<T>` to `BaseState<T> CurrentState` in my first interface.

> Using the generic type BaseState need 1 type arguments

But how could I tell him that T is the class that implements my interface ?

I tried some stuff, like adding a generic to my interface

```
public interface IStateMachine<T> where T : IStateMachine<T>
{
    public BaseState<T> CurrentState { get; set; }
}
```

but it simply tell me

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BaseState'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'IStateMachine'.

I'm probably missing a simple fact about generics, and this question might be a duplicate of  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817687/c-sharp-generics-cross-referencing-classes-for-state-pattern) (state machine, unity, but from 7 years ago).

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps you are interested in the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CurrentState Property inside the IStateMachine probably references to the BaseState which needs a generic type. Either way your structure seem a bit tough because it kind of has a recursive link. IStateMachine needs a BaseState but a BaseState needs a IStateMachine?

I would suggest not trying to let the BaseState know what StateMachine it is attached to.

Another suggestion would be to create another Class "StateMachineContext" which the BaseState has a reference to and this StateMachineContext has a reference to IStateMachine.

Yet another approach would be to have it similiar to the following code:

```
public interface IStateMachine
{
    public BaseState CurrentState { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseState
{
    // Some functionality that IStateMachine needs access 
    // to.
}

public abstract class BaseState<T> : BaseState where T : IStateMachine
{
    private T _ctx;
    // ... other state stuffs
}
```

Another very simple way to begin a statemachine:
(Instead of providing the Data in the state as a reference you could also pass it as a parameter with whatever function you will call on the state.)

```
public class Entity
{
    public IStateMachine<Entity> StateMachine { get; set; }
}
public interface IStateMachine<T>
{
    public BaseState<T> CurrentState { get; set; }
    // Some generic state handling functionality
}
public abstract class BaseState<T>
{
    private T _ctx;
    /*
     Some required state handling that will
     be called by the entity through the statemachine 
    */
}
```

Comment: I have to let the State know about the StateMachine because it expose all the information the state need to work (NavMeshAgent, sensor, etc.). Your last approach solved my problem, but as my machine become more complex maybe the Context class will be more robust

Comment: @DamienAr Reading your comment I added another proposal on how to implement a simple StateMachine. Just remember to not overengineer it and keep it simple. You can always make it more generic if you require to later on but like this it probably is good enough. Premature optimization is a killer sometimes. ( As a side Note I've implemented State Machines like this but not for Unity so I am unsure how well it fits in.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you do not declare the type when you make the actual state implementation:

```
public class StateMachine : IStateMachine
... 
public class StateA : BaseState<StateMachine > // need to specify T
public class StateB<T>: BaseState<T> where T : IStateMachine // let caller specify T
```

But the problem you will run into is that you have to declare all the methods and properties you want to use on the common base type. States need to reference each other, so you will need to use the base type in these references. So you will not really gain anything by using generics.

A workaround for this is to use the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). i.e.

```
public abstract class BaseState<T> where T: BaseState<T>{
    public T Next {get;}
```

This essentially gives a way to promise that the entire graph of states will have a common type. This can still allow for methods that do things like traversing the graph, without any need to know the actual type, for example:

```
public static T NextNext<T>(BaseState<T> start) where T : BaseState<T>{ 
    return start.Next.Next;
}

public class MyState : BaseState<MyState>{
    ...
}
var myState = new MyState(...);
MyState nn = myState.NextNext(); // Keep the type when traversing the graph
```

Comment: I tried to fiddle around with the crtp and it doesn't seem to work in C# as it does in C++ because C# enforces type relations stronger when the template is compiled. For that reason we cannot call an unknown function in the base class after casting `this` to an unrelated (unrelated when we compile the base) type, the way it is shown in the Wikipedia page. In C++ that works because a template is always compiled in the context of its use, and the viability of `static_cast<T*>(this)->implementation();` (does T have that function?) can then be checked. Not so in C#.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It should work the same, just that you can get around it with `public class EvilClass : BaseState<OtherState>`

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica crtp work fine in c#, but the details might be a bit different due to the differences between c++ templates and c# generics. So some applications, like static polymorphism, are not applicable to c#. In this context it is used for ensuring a graph of objects share a common type.

Comment: @JonasH Ah, thanks for the clarification. The benefit of your use case compared to a simple non-generic base class seems to be better types and the absence of the need to cast (`NextNext` can return a proper T -- here: MyState -- and not only a `BaseState`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my problem is with the interface, not with the BaseState class. My question might be a little misleading.
But I didn't know this crtp pattern, thank you and peter for letting me know about it